# Tensorflow feeding image in memory

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I receive an image from network which I convert to a numpy array using `fromfile` function. Now I want to pass this `unit8` type array to `decode_image` of tensorflow v1. How can I achieve that? I do not want to have a file on disk and do it all in-memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the answer is pretty simple. Supposed `nd` is the 1-D array returned from `fromfile` then you can call function `tostring` and pass that to `decode_image` of tensorflow.